# vuejs2 with select option get the value and other attribute

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm using vuejs.
Let's say I have select and inside I have multiple options
like this:

```
<select  v-model='line.unit' name='unit[]' required @change='change_unit($event)'>
    <option v-for='(unit) in line.units' price='line.price' :value='unit.id'>@{{unit['get_unit_id']['name']}}</option>
    <option selected class='selected' price='line.price' v-if='line.smallest_unit' :value='line.smallest_unit.id'>@{{line.smallest_unit['name']}}</option>
</select>
```

And this is the change_unit method:

```
change_unit:function($event)
{

}
```

How can I access the attribute `price` if I want the value of the selected option? I can get it like this ..

```
console.log(event.target.value);
```

But now can I access the price value attribute?

Comment: Did you already have a look on watchers: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers?

Comment: not watchers what i want what i want is to get custom attribute value

Comment: A component that might help, https://vue-select.org/ I use it a lot personally.

Comment: could you please post an example of your `data { ... }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could tweak the option `value` binding it to Vue.js
as you can see in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y3vja7ft/1), which I'll explain here

Consider this HTML

```
<div id="app">
  <select v-model="line.unit" name='unit[]' required>
      <option v-for='(unit) in line.units' :value="unit">
            {{unit.name}}
        </option>
  </select>

  <h2 v-if="line.unit">
     {{line.unit.price}}
  </h2>
</div>
```

As you can see, I'm setting the `<option>` value binding it to `unit`, which is each single `line.units` item object. by doing that, selecting an option will actually set the `v-model` to `unit`, instead of an object's attribute

Consider this JS, in which I've created a hypotetic reproduction of your `.data`.

```
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data() {
      return {
        line: {
          unit: {},
          units: [{
            id: 1,
            price: 100,
            name: 'foo'
          },{
            id: 2,
            price: 200,
            name: 'bar'
          }]
        }
      }
    }
  })
```

Selecting an option will now show you it's price (I've put a `<h2>` as a demonstration)